# Solaris missing memory

Tags: solaris, sun

I have two identical Sun/Oracle Netra X4250s both with 16 x 4096MB DIMMs (as reported by memconf.pl, prtdiag and the ILOM)

On one, prtconf shows 64768MB but the other shows 57344MB

16 x 4096 = 65536 so where is the missing memory and why is one showing 7424MB less than the other?

Neither server shows any hardware faults.

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/system`?  Does it have a `physmem` entry?  What's the output from `fmadm faulty`?

Comment: /etc/system is the same across both boxes (verified with md5sum) and nothing about physmem.  fmadm faulty comes back blank for both.  I tried to post the contents of /etc/system but there were no line breaks

Comment: If you have console access and can reboot the boxes, what does the BIOS show for RAM?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only got approval to reboot one and the BIOS does, indeed show 57GB.  Looks like we'll be getting some hardware support out on site.

Comment: If you can shut down for a bit, I'd crack the box open and check to make sure the memory you think is there really is.  And if the memory you expect is installed, reseat the memory modules.